# Where to install shared libraries on OSX 10.11?

Tags: macos, dylib, osx-elcapitan

Since OSX 10.11 it is forbidden to put stuff into /usr/lib, so I redirected everything to /usr/local/lib, which is afaik THE folder to install user libraries to. But /usr/local usually doesn't exist, so the installer creates it. It seems working fine, I checked only on 10.11 beta though, but others say it is fine.

But now I ran into a customer, who used official upgrade to 10.11 (not beta) and the system forbids him to create /usr/local directory, he even tried manually...
Any ideas what the hell is this about?

Comment: System Integrity Protection.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Apple tightened the security of OS X to prevent apps manipulating with system files.

Watch this Apple presentation to get answer and suggestions on what to do going forward.

[Apple's App Transport Security presentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-706/)

Comment: Can you provide a link to Apple documentation that will tell me where to put shared libraries?  And best practices for including them in an application?

Comment: What are the purpose of the shared library? Shared between multiple apps created by you or your team?

Comment: There are two problems I want to solve.  1: the libraries are separate projects that are also under development, so putting headers and librariess in /usr/local means that they are not in version control. 2: where do the libraries belong when it becomes time to make an installer.  I think perhaps the libraries should be made into Frameworks, is that right?  (I'm relatively inexperienced with Xcode and MacOS)

Comment: Imbedded frameworks and self-contained app containers are the way to go. If your new to Xcode development I suggest https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE83F832121568D36 for learning.